# "Rollback to Revision n" doesn't appear consistently

Tags: support, editing

When a post is rolled back via the 'edit' option, it prepends

> Rollback to Revision *n* -

automatically to the edit summary, but not consistently.

---

- Is there a criteria for adding this text?
- Should the behaviour be consistent?

---

Examples:

[Text was automatically added](https://meta.askubuntu.com/revisions/7773/3)
[Text wasn't added](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/419304/4)

However, one was on Meta and the other on main so that may be the difference.